# Как добавить контекстное меню для нескольких Entry и Text?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, text

Вот код-набросок:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

can = Canvas(root, bg="white")
can.pack()

text1 = Entry(can, bg="white", fg="black", width=50)
text1.grid(column=1,row=1)

text2 = Entry(can, bg="white", fg="black", width=50)
text2.grid(column=2,row=1)

text3 = Entry(can, bg="white", fg="black", width=50)
text3.grid(column=3,row=1)


root.mainloop()
```

---

Как сделать, чтобы  было как на Фотографии, при нажатии ПКМ на `Enrty` или `Text` появлялось контекстное меню с кнопками: вырезать выделенный текст или вырезать. Как это можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: связанный вопрос [tkinter app adding a right click context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12014210/4279)

Comment: Практически да, но как вместо `Listbox` использовать `Text` или `Entry`, я имею ввиду: вырезать, скопировать выделенный текст или вставить на выделенный текст

Comment: Да "Связанный вопрос", но только для одного виджета

Comment: @jfs Этот вопрос практически отличаются от того, там в ответе только на 1 виджет(и то только для Text), а мне надо на 3 виджета(Entry).

Comment: @jfs **Что является дубликатом в моем вопросе?**

Comment: информацию типа: я знаю как для одного виджета сделать задачу, но хочу для 3, необходимо прямо в вопрос добавлять.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Stardand context menu in Python TKinter text widget when mouse right button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266566/stardand-context-menu-in-python-tkinter-text-widget-when-mouse-right-button-is-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой вариант: наследуемся от `tk.Text`, в новом классе добавляем появление контекстного меню, реализуем все нужные операции. И дальше уже создаем виджеты не класса `tk.Text`, а своего класса.

Реализовал для `tk.Text` и `tk.Entry` при помощи множественного наследования. Уверен, что в данном случае множественное наследование можно сделать более правильно, буду рад если кто-то прокомментирует.

```
import tkinter as tk

class AddPopupMenu:
    def copy_selection(self):
        try:
            selection_text = self.selection_get()
        except tk.TclError:
            return

        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(selection_text)
        print('Copied:', selection_text)

    def delete_selection(self):
        try:
            self.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')
        except tk.TclError:
            pass  # Nothing selected

    def cut_selection(self):
        self.copy_selection()
        self.delete_selection()

    def paste_from_clipboard(self):
        try:
            clipboard_text = root.clipboard_get()
        except tk.TclError:
            pass
        else:
            self.delete_selection()
            self.insert(tk.INSERT, clipboard_text)

    def select_all(self):
        # Пример отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808423/4752653
        self.tag_add(tk.SEL, "1.0", tk.END)
        self.mark_set(tk.INSERT, "1.0")
        self.see(tk.INSERT)

    def show_context_menu(self, event):
        pos_x = self.winfo_rootx() + event.x
        pos_y = self.winfo_rooty() + event.y
        self.popup_menu.tk_popup(pos_x, pos_y)

    def init_menu(self):
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_command(label="Вырезать", command=self.cut_selection)
        menu.add_command(label="Копировать", command=self.copy_selection)
        menu.add_command(label="Вставить", command=self.paste_from_clipboard)
        menu.add_command(label="Удалить", command=self.delete_selection)
        menu.add_separator()
        menu.add_command(label="Выделить все", command=self.select_all)
        return menu

    def __init__(self, widget_class, *args, **kwargs):
        widget_class.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.popup_menu = self.init_menu()
        self.bind("<3>", self.show_context_menu)


class MyText(tk.Text, AddPopupMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        AddPopupMenu.__init__(self, tk.Text, *args, **kwargs)


class MyEntry(tk.Entry, AddPopupMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        AddPopupMenu.__init__(self, tk.Entry, *args, **kwargs)


root = tk.Tk()

text1 = MyText(root, width=50, height=10)
text1.pack()

text2 = MyText(root, width=50, height=10)
text2.pack()

entry1 = MyEntry(root, width=50)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = MyEntry(root, width=50)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А как сделать не для одного виджета, а для нескольких?

Comment: @оаавирыыва, по идее можно привязать одно и то же меню, но в обработчиках нужно как-то определять активный виджет. Либо создавать отдельное меню для каждого виджета, и в обработчики передавать виджет (как в примере в ответе).

Comment: Через `event.widget` должно получится, узнать какой `Entry` задействован

Comment: Либо через class реализовать можно будет, но лучше через event, чтоб мне весь свой код не переделывать

Comment: @оаавирыыва, реализовал пример для нескольких виджетов.

Comment: А как теперь сделать еще для вырезать, вставить, выделить все, очистить?

Comment: @оаавирыыва, добавил

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, а для Entry получится сделать?

Comment: Можно не создавать свои функции, а использовать встроенные такие как [`<<Cut>> <<Copy>> ` и т.д.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814653/255866), что по сути сократит код.

Comment: @Twiss, исправил

Answer (score 3):

Чуть укороченный вариант с использованием встроенных событий.
В данном случае вы задаете

```
entry_1.bind_class("Entry", "<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", func)
```

как использовании функции под определенный класс (в данном случае `Entry`). После чего в этой(`func`)  [прописываете действия](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/event.htm#M69) (к примеру

```
lambda: w.focus_force() or w.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
```

что по сути является выделением виджета и вырезанием определенного выделенного текста)

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.menu = tk.Menu(tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Вырезать", accelerator="Ctrl+X", command=lambda: self.w.focus_force() or self.w.event_generate("<<Cut>>"))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Копировать", accelerator="Ctrl+С", command=lambda: self.w.focus_force() or self.w.event_generate("<<Copy>>"))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Вставить", accelerator="Ctrl+V", command=lambda: self.w.focus_force() or self.w.event_generate("<<Paste>>"))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Удалить", accelerator="Delete", command=lambda: self.w.focus_force() or self.w.event_generate("<<Clear>>"))
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label="Выделить все", accelerator="Ctrl+A", command=lambda: self.w.focus_force() or self.w.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>"))

        entry_1 = tk.Entry()
        entry_1.pack()

        entry_2 = tk.Entry()
        entry_2.pack()
        entry_3 = tk.Entry()
        entry_3.pack()

        text = tk.Text()
        text.pack()
        text.bind("<Button-3>", self.func)
        self.bind_class("Entry", "<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.func)

    def func(self, event):

        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        self.w = event.widget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<<Cut>>` и прочее - это не функции, а виртуальные события (что кстати указано в приведенной вами ссылке). И еще поправьте `"функции прописываете функции прописываете действия"` - тут явно что-то не так.